# Default test expression behaves different in zsh vs bash - why?

Tags: bash, zsh

Here is a simple test case script which behaves differently in zsh vs bash when I run with `$ source test_script.sh` from the command line. I don't necessarily know why there is a difference if my shebang clearly states that I want bash to run my script other than the fact that the `which` command is a built-in in zsh and a program in bash.  (FYI - the shebang directory is where my bash program lives which may not be the same as yours--I installed a new version using homebrew)

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
if [ "$(which ls)" ]; then
    echo "ls command found"
else 
    echo "ls command not found"
fi

if [ "$(which foo)" ]; then
    echo "foo command found"
else
    echo "foo command not found"
```

I run this script with `source ./test-script.sh` from zsh and Bash.

Output in zsh:

```
ls command found
foo command found
```

Output in bash:

```
ls command found
foo command not found
```

My understanding is that default for `test` or `[ ]` (which are the same thing) evaluate a string to true if it's not empty/null.  To illustrate:

zsh:

```
$ which foo
foo not found
```

bash:

```
$ which foo

$
```

Moreover if I redirect standard error in zsh like:

```
$ which foo 2> /dev/null
foo not found
```

zsh still seems to send `foo not found` to standard output which is why (I am guessing) my test case passed for both under the zshell; because the expansion of `"$(which xxx)"` returned a string in both cases (e.g. `/some/directory` and `foo not found` (zsh will ALWAYS return a string?).

Lastly, if I remove the double quotes (e.g. `$(which xxx)`), zsh gives me an error.  Here is the output:

```
ls command found
test_scritp.sh:27: condition expected not:
```

I am guessing zsh wanted me to use `[ ! "$(which xxx)" ]`.  I don't understand why?  It never gave that error when running in bash (and isn't this supposed to run in bash anyway?!).

Why isn't my script using bash?  Why is something so trivial as this not working?  I understand how to make it work fine in both using the `-e` option but I simply want to understand why this is all happening.  Its driving me bonkers.

Comment: Why would you test the text output instead of just testing the return code?

Comment: Concur: Testing for an empty string is an antipattern when what you really want to test is whether a command succeeded.  The reason commands return an exit code is precisely so that you can use them in an `if` or `while` condition.

Comment: And to top it off, `which` is not the proper way to test for a command.  Use the POSIX command `type`.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, I am not sure I understand your comment.  First, I am a newbie.  Second, are you referring to `$?` as the "return code"?.  This test should pass both zsh and bash, especially if I am calling it to be executed by bash.  Please explain why it does't work.  That is what my question is...NOT how to test the same thing in a different way that does work-I already know how to do that and referenced that in my question.

Comment: @tripleee, thanks for the comments but again, I am new, and trying to understand why this simple script doesn't work.  NOT, how to test differently which I referenced in my answer.

Comment: If you are running the script using the shebang (i.e. just `./script`) then it is being run under Bash.  It's still possible that `zsh` provides it with a different environment.

Comment: Yes, the command's return code is visible in `$?` but since the shell's control statements examine this variable under the hood, you very rarely need to examine it explicitly.  In your script, the correct, idiomatic way to do what you are attempting would be `if type foo; then ...` (perhaps with redirection to get it to run quietly).

Comment: @tripleee why?  isn't that the whole point of shebang haha.  I was running it  as follows `$ source test_script.sh`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123827/discussion-between-tripleee-and-tommyc38).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two separate problems here.

First, the proper command to use is `type`,  not `which`.  Like you note, the command `which` is a `zsh` built-in, whereas in Bash, it will execute whatever `which` command happens to be on your system.  There are many variants with different behaviors, which is why POSIX opted to introduce a replacement instead of trying to prescribe a particular behavior for `which` -- then there would be yet one more possible behavior, and no way to easily root out all the other legacy behaviors.  (One early common problem was with a `which` command which would examine the `csh` environment, even if you actually used a different shell.)

Secondly, examining a command's string output is a serious antipattern, because strings differ between locales ("not found" vs. "nicht gefunden" vs. "ei löytynyt" vs. etc etc) and program versions -- the proper solution is to examine the command's exit code.

```
if type ls >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "ls command found"
else
    echo "ls command not found"
fi

if type foo >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "foo command found"
else
    echo "foo command not found"
fi
```

(A related antipattern is to examine `$?` explicitly.  There is very rarely any need to do this, as it is done naturally and transparently by the shell's flow control statements, like `if` and `while`.)

Regarding quoting, the shell performs whitespace tokenization and wildcard expansion on unquoted values, so if `$string` is `command not found`, the expression

```
[ $string ]
```

without quotes around the value evaluates to

```
[ command not found ]
```

which looks to the shell like the string "command" followed by some cruft which isn't syntactically valid.

Lastly, as we uncovered in the chat session (linked from comments) the OP was confused about the precise meaning of `source`, and ended up running a Bash script in a separate process instead.  (`./test-script` instead of `source ./test-script`).  For the record, when you `source` a file, you cause your current shell to read and execute it; in this setting, the script's shebang line is simply a comment, and is completely ignored by the shell.

Comment: ++; on a side note: `type` is by definition a _built-in_ command in all POSIX-compatible shells (["Since `type` must be aware of the contents of the current shell execution environment (...), it is always provided as a shell regular built-in."](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/type.html)). The spec isn't explicit about how to report non-existent commands; `bash`, `ksh`, and `dash` went for the sensible option of printing to _stderr_ in that event; `zsh`, by contrast, opted for _stdout_ (as it did with its `which` built-in).